# Bootstrap full height column with overflow scroll doesn't work in firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with the firefox issue related to flex and overflow. I know the fix is to add min-height: 0 to the parent element, but I can't get it to work. I've tried adding min-height: 0 to every ancestor of the scrollable elements but I can't get it to work in firefox (chrome is fine). Here is the code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdbwqE

```css
.scroll-y {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> Formatted HTML:

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
      <div class="col p-0">
        <h3>Navbar</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-lg-grow-1">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-2 d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">Header</div>
          <div class="flex-grow-1 h-100 scroll-y">
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
            <div>Sidebar</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
        <div class="h-100 scroll-y">
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```